# The driver \Driver\WUDFRd failed to load for the device ROOT\DISPLAY\0000

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, windows-11

Getting Warning Event ID 219 as listed in the title. Following a similar question's advice, I set my Nvidia card (RTX 3090) to Performance mode in the Nvidia Control Panel.

This is happening when trying to boot video games (Call of Duty on Steam, Fortnite). Sometimes I can get into a game, sometimes not. This error is immediately followed by Critical Event ID 41, the system shuts down on its own.

At first I thought this was a GPU issue, as the Performance change fixed it for about a month, but then I thought the PSU was bad, as it was an 800w when the 3090 calls for 1000 or above. But I just switched it out for a 1200w PSU, and I'm still getting the same issue. Prior to last month, I never had these issues.